# Attachment uploaded using base64 encode is throwing an error

Tags: rest-api, api, attachment, base64

I am trying to upload a pdf file from anonymous block using the following code

```
public static Id saveTheFile(Id parentId, String fileName, String base64Data, String contentType) { 
    base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'iso-8859-15');

    Attachment a = new Attachment();
    a.parentId = parentId;

    a.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
    a.Name = fileName;
    a.ContentType = contentType;

    insert a;

    return a.Id;
}
```

Here for base64Data, I have encoded a pdf file online and passed it to the method from anonymous block

The attachment is getting correctly uploaded, however, when I try to view the pdf, it is showing 'Error: failed to load'. Where am I making a mistake here?

Comment: You don't need to url decode. A direct base64 string can be converted into blob.

Comment: Yes. It worked. Would you like to add this comment as an answer? I will mark it as correct @PranayJaiswal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to url decode. A  base64 string can be directly converted into blob.